# Organize and Manage Remote Desktop Sessions

Tags: information-management, remote-desktop

In our company we have a list of Windows PCs that are available via Remote Desktop to a lot of users. As we haven't got enough remote machines for everyone, and not everybody needs one all the time, we share them.

In order for this to work, we need a central point where users can have a look which PCs are currently not used by anyone else so that they can grab one.

Our current approach is a list that is accessible via our Intranet, which has to be updated manually by the users. That means if someone is finished using that machine, that person has to manually update the list to make that pc available again for others.

This approach is a huge pain in the ass, since most of the time the users forget to update the list. That's why we decided we want to change that and use software that manages all that.
It should have those features:

When a user wants to connect to a PC, he is able to see at one glance which ones are currently available

When a user decided for one PC and connects to it, this PC should automatically be markes as unusable for others

When a user disconnects from that machine, it will automatically be markes as usable for others again

When a user needs a machine for a longer period of time, he can reserve it for himself, so that the machine is still marked as unuseable for others as long as his reservation is valid. It would be optimal to configure a max. reservation time.

The software should be self hosted, as those machines have got no access to the internet. So any remote managing software that uses cloud features or a constant connection to the internet is ruled out.

I searched quite some time for a software that can do that, but so far have not found something. I stumbled accross [https://remotedesktopmanager.com/][1] but it seems that it can't to quite everything we need.

We've also considered creating an Application that can do all that by ourselves, which should not be that big of a problem since our company produces software. We just wanted to be sure that there is nothing on the market that meets our requirements before investing to much time of our own.

I'm really looking forward to hear your ideas!

Best Regards